# creating python whl with directories outside package

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to create a package that has the following structure:

```
project/
    plugin_dir/
    templates/
    sh/
```

I have a setup.py file like the following:

```
setup(name='my_plugin',
      version='1.0.0',
      packages=['my_plugin'],
      install_requires=['slackclient>=1.0.5', 'airflow==1.8', 'snakebite>=2.11.0', 'prometheus-client>=0.0.19'],
      dependency_links=[],
      # scripts=findall('sh/')+findall('templates/'),
      data_files=[('/sh', findall('sh/'))],
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False
      )
```

I run the command `python setup.py bdist_wheel` and it doesn't include the files from sh or templates directory when I look in the wheel.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind it works fine, I didn't see it in the build/ but once you unpack the wheel running `pip install my_plugin --target . --no-deps` it's included.